# Finding the average of the data in Excel 2021 for the similar first column data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a huge data and the following image is a part of my data,
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5M0S.png]

First column is always a natural number (not necessary consecutive) and for the rows which have the same first column data I want to find the average of each of its next column data. For example first three cells on the first column is 142 and I want to find the average of next three cells of each next columns. Since I have lot's of data I want to make this process automatic I tried "AVERAGEIF" formula but with no result. Can you please help me?

Comment: 140 appears only twice and then 139 as well. What happens in thsese cases?

Comment: @karl The number of repetition is not known. For example it is possible that the next row start with 134 with any repetition. Or it can also appear once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you did provide your data only as a picture, I created some random data as follows in the range `A1:E17`:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 142 | 0.02 | 0.19 | 0.83 | 0.14 |
| 142 | 0.65 | 0.61 | 0.38 | 0.82 |
| 142 | 0.60 | 0.34 | 0.36 | 0.37 |
| 141 | 0.98 | 0.95 | 0.23 | 0.97 |
| 141 | 0.83 | 0.24 | 0.50 | 0.67 |
| 141 | 0.02 | 0.14 | 0.33 | 0.23 |
| 140 | 0.33 | 0.14 | 0.85 | 0.64 |
| 140 | 0.78 | 0.09 | 0.17 | 0.06 |
| 139 | 0.08 | 0.70 | 0.26 | 0.26 |
| 139 | 0.25 | 0.16 | 0.35 | 0.67 |
| 138 | 0.52 | 0.44 | 0.18 | 0.44 |
| 138 | 0.21 | 0.93 | 0.04 | 0.23 |
| 138 | 0.66 | 0.33 | 0.72 | 0.39 |
| 138 | 0.91 | 0.91 | 0.51 | 0.30 |
| 137 | 0.39 | 0.60 | 0.28 | 0.46 |
| 137 | 0.43 | 0.81 | 0.41 | 0.14 |

Now, you put in, e.g., cell `G2` and `H2` the following formulas respectively; the `AVERAGEIF()` formula can be repeated for the additional columns:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE($A$2:$A$17))
=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$17,$G$2#,B2:B17)
```

Now some additional explanation; the `UNIQUE()` function can be used to extract the unique IDs. This function returns an array, which can then be used for the `AVERAGEIF()` such that it automatically spills. The `SORT()` function is used to put the ID values in ascending order. For the `AVERAGEIF()` function, you first specify the range where you want to lookup the ID, e.g., in your column `A`. Next you specify the criteria, which is your array that we obtained with `UNIQUE()` and last you specify the column over which you want to average.

The output will look as follows:

| ID | Avg. |
| --- | --- |
| 137 | 0.41 |
| 138 | 0.57 |
| 139 | 0.17 |
| 140 | 0.55 |
| 141 | 0.61 |
| 142 | 0.42 |

---

**Extension to access all averages as one array and having all formulas in one cell:**

Depending on the use case, you might be interested to access all averages as one array. To achieve this, you can wrap your `AVERAGEIF()` functions inside a `HSTACK()`. In that way, the formula spills down because of the `UNIQUE()` function and to the right because of the `HSTACK()` function. In that way, you also have all formulas in a single cell, which might also sometimes easier to maintain:

```
=HSTACK(
AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$17,$G$2#,B2:B17),
AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$17,$G$2#,C2:C17),
AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$17,$G$2#,D2:D17),
AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$17,$G$2#,E2:E17)
)
```

Assuming the formula is still in cell `H2`, you can access the complete array as follows:

```
=SUM(H2#)
```

---

**Extension based on comment to include dynamic range:**

To achieve this, you could use a `LET()` statement as follows:

```
=LET(
    lastCol, "E",
    data, INDEX(A:A,2):INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(lastCol, ":", lastCol)),
    MAX(IF(A:A<>"", ROW(A:A)))),
    id, SORT(UNIQUE(INDEX(data,2,1):INDEX(data,ROWS(data),1))),
    b, AVERAGEIF(INDEX(data,,1), id, INDEX(data,,2)),
    c, AVERAGEIF(INDEX(data,,1), id, INDEX(data,,3)),
    d, AVERAGEIF(INDEX(data,,1), id, INDEX(data,,4)),
    e, AVERAGEIF(INDEX(data,,1), id, INDEX(data,,5)),
    HSTACK(id,b,c,d,e)
)
```

First, you specify your "last" column with data. The number of rows is automatically computed based on column `A`, thus, you need to ensure that you do not have any data below the data that you want to use.
All other aspects are similar to what we had before, just wrapped in a `LET()` statement, which allows you to dynamically access the data range via `INDEX()` because it can store intermediate results.

This approach will achieve what you asked for. The caveat, however, it does not necessarily scale very well to many columns, because right now it requires you to repeat the formula for each column. In theory, it should be possible to make also this dimension more dynamic, but it goes beyond the scope of this extension here.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Just wanted to add if someone is too lazy (or efficient like me :D) they can use `=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$17,$G$2#,B2:B17)` and then extend to other columns!

Comment: Your answer has helped me a lot. Just one question: Is it possible to apply thease functions from the starting cell till the last cell in the column without specifying the last one in the formula?

Comment: @Etemon See the edit of the answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

In F2: `=AVERAGE(IF($A$2:$A$17=$A2,B$2:B$17))`

In G2: `=AVERAGE(IF($A$2:$A$17=$A2,C$2:C$17))`

In H2: `=AVERAGE(IF($A$2:$A$17=$A2,D$2:D$17))`

In I2: `=AVERAGE(IF($A$2:$A$17=$A2,E$2:E$17))`

[image]

Note: This is an array formula. In earlier versions of Excel, you must press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to make the formula work. The current version of Excel can simply press `Enter`.